# :symbol to Constant in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a method in Rails that converts a symbol to a constant?  I want to be able to do something like

```
:monkey.to_constant #=> Monkey
```

At the moment I have to do

```
:monkey.to_s.camelize.constantize
```

which is a bit of a mouthful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Symbol
  def to_c
    self.to_s.camelize.constantize
  end
end

:monkey.to_c
```

**Updated for Rails >= 4**

As of Rails >= 4 `.classify` is better to use than `.camelize`

```
# .camelize with singular and plural symbols/strings
:user.to_s.camelize.constantize
# => User
:users.to_s.camelize.constantize
# => NameError: uninitialized constant Users

# .classify with singular and plural symbols/strings
:user.to_s.classify.constantize
# => User
:users.to_s.classify.constantize
# => User
```

Comment: I believe I've just seen monkey patching defined :)