# rails: How do I convert a symbol to a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a symbol in rails, how do I get a Class?  So I could call something like:

```
give_class(:post).find(:all)
```

or similar.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First, convert to string.

```
class_name = symbol.to_s
```

From there, you will need to format the string into a proper class name using the methods provided by [ActiveSupport's Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html).

- `camelize` will turn `'my_module'` into `'MyModule'`
- `classify` will turn `'my_models'` into `'MyModel'`

`camelize` is more likely the one you want, given your code snippet.

Then use the `constantize` method:

```
klass = class_name.constantize
```

Classy!

Answer (score 4):

I was searching stackoverflow for this answer and couldn't find it worded how I was looking for it, so I thought I would Q&A myself:

- [:symbol to Constant in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618607/symbol-to-constant-in-rails)

The answer above was correct, but I acutally found the docs that explain a bit better:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001360

There are basically two methods:

- .to_s.camelize - used when you have the singular form (:post)
- .to_s.classify - used when you have a plural form (:posts)

From that, you call constantize, and Viola! you have your class.

Comment: Mhm. It depends on if you are going to be passing in the actual class name `:MyClass`, or prefer the `:my_class` format.

Comment: Yeah, that is right.  That was the part that was tripping me up.  Especially the difference between singular and plural.

Comment: Looks like there is an updated version for Rails 3  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: accidental downvote - cannot undo till you edit, sorry